# Insert tr in table at 0th position

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have the jQuery object of table rows and I have use the following code snippet to insert the table row:

```
 $(proxy._gridRows).eq(args.recordIndex).after(addedGridRow);

Here proxy._gridRows =Table Rows
     args.recordIndex=0;
     addedGridRow =html string for tr;
```

In this case row inserted into the first index. How to insert the table row in the 0th index?

Comment: Use the `prependTo` method. `$(proxy._gridRows).eq(args.recordIndex).prependTo(parent)`

Comment: @Raja 22 QUESTIONS AND NOT ACCEPTED ANSWERS AT ALL!? This is not how SO works. Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) some answers.

Answer (score 1):

use `prepend` on the `table` as

```
table.prepend(row)
```

**table** is jquery table element

**row**   is jquery tr element which you want to insert at 0th position in table